# how to use case when to reassign value to variable

Tags: sql

I use a data management system that works using SQL. It allows users to select values and then queries are run to fetch data based on the user inputs. For my problem, a user has the option to input a specific location (city) for the equipment they are looking up in a certain state and when they don't enter anything, the location_id defaults to 0. I am trying to code the logic so that if the location id is 0, the it will query all location_id's in that state. and if the user does input a specific location it will just use that location_id.

```
select * from equipment e 
where e.equipment_type = 4
and e.start_date <= '2022-01-31'
and (e.end_date is null or e.end_date > '2022-01-01')
and e.state = 'TX'
and (
case when e.location_id = 0 then e.location_id in (
select location_id
from equipment e 
where e.equipment_type = 4
and e.start_date <= '2022-01-31'
and (e.end_date is null or e.end_date > '2022-01-01')
and e.state = 'TX')
else e.location_id in {location_id}
)
```

this is the code I came up with and the {location_id} is the syntax in my system to use the input the user selected. I am unsure of how to better code this logic and get the case when to work. Any help would be appreciated

---

Comment: which databse system are you using?

Comment: also when e.location_ud is 0, your select will be unnecessary  as you wpuld compare all ids to 0

Comment: Skip the case expression, use regular AND/OR instead. I.e. `...and (e.location_id = {location_id} or {location_id} = 0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you amend your case statement as below, then it should work. Idea is if passed in value is 0 then compare location_id with location_id which will evaluate to true.

```
select * from equipment e 
where e.equipment_type = 4
and e.start_date <= '2022-01-31'
and (e.end_date is null or e.end_date > '2022-01-01')
and e.state = 'TX'
and e.location_id = case when {location_id} = 0 then e.location_id else {location_id} end
```

Comment: if the user could put input multiple location ID's and I want it to create the case when so it'll be e.location_id in (input1, input2, input3), how would I modify this code?

Comment: It would depend on how you are going to pass the multiple location ids to the query. Are you going to pass them as fixed list of variables or in a table variable or in a temp table. Btw, which database are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

you can set @locationid to zero or 1 to see output

```
--input parameter
DECLARE @locationid int = 0 --can set zero or 1 or null (null will default to zero)

--set example table variable
DECLARE @equipment TABLE (equipment_type INT, start_date DATETIME, end_date DATETIME, location_id INT, state CHAR(2))
--populated data
INSERT INTO @equipment (equipment_type,start_date,end_date,location_id,state)
VALUES
(4, '2022-01-02', '2022-02-02', 0, 'TX'),
(4, '2022-01-02', '2022-02-02', 1, 'TX'),
(4, '2022-01-02', '2022-02-02', 0, 'TX')

SELECT * from @equipment e 
where e.equipment_type = 4
and e.start_date <= '2022-01-31'
and (e.end_date is null or e.end_date > '2022-01-01')
and e.state = 'TX'
and e.location_id = CASE WHEN COALESCE(@locationid, 0) = 0 then 0 
                        ELSE @locationid end
```